# Enforce theme in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to enforce the lightmode theme to my android application.

I've added this line of code to the app.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Light;
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
```

I read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/system-theme-changes but don't understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by placing this line of code in the MainActivity.cs from the Android project

```
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```

Placing this line of code directly at the start of the OnCreate method solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `App.Current.UserAppTheme` is not enough, you have to define your light or/and dark theme through styles for different controls using the xaml extension `AppThemeBinding` like shown in examples in documentation link.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't really understand the documentation. I have however solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to make your XF app cross platform and you will not be toggling between themes you can force light theme on iOS by setting OverrideUserInterfaceStyle  in your custom page renderer:

```
using TheNameSpace;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace TheNameSpace
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            OverrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyle.Light;
        }
    }
}
```